# Passing variables to django template from view

Tags: python, django

In my base.html, i have the following code

```
{% if user_anon == "true" %}
    {% block login_with_fb %}{% endblock %}
{% else %}
    SOMETHING ELSE
```

And in views.py , i have

```
t = get_template('login.html')
try:
    c = Context({ 'user_anon':"false" , 'STATIC_URL':'/stic'})
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    c = Context({ 'user_anon':"true" , 'STATIC_URL':'/stic'})
r = t.render(c)
return HttpResponse(r)
```

but the base.html always responds with user_anon = "true" code... irrespective of the value of c being passed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not check the request directly in the template?

Example:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

Secondly, why are you casting it to a string? It would be easier to just use true/false in Python I would think.

Lastly, why are you injecting your static url? You should be setting this in your configuration, then you can just use it directly via template tag. See the official docs about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

Example:

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

Comment: That was the first thing i tried, `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` and it didn't work... since i am using an external library for login, i really have no clue where the variable "user.is_authenticated" is set to be true and how to modify it, so went with the custom variables.

Comment: If that value is not accessible, it probably means you are not passing your request context to your template properly.

Also you can try to do  as I suggested, don't pass string to your template, use a Python True/False which is cleaner IMO. Also, why are you not using render_to_response shortcut? It would simplify your code a bit here.

Comment: turns out that instead of `user.is_authenticated` ... i needed to use `user.is_anonymous` to make it work. Probably the library is old school :P Thanks for the help.